# A regular expression for using an email address as username?

Tags: regex, asp.net-mvc, validation, data-annotations

Is there a regular expression out there for using a normal username OR an email address as a username? I would like a user to be able to enter their own username, or just use their email address as the username and I am unable to find any reliable information on how to achieve this properly. It would still have to pass validation as well, for example: if the user chooses to make their own username, it would have to abide by my policy for usernames, which limits them to starting with a letter or number, and no special characters, or if they enter an email, it would have to abide by the email rules(typical email rules). Anyone have a suggestion for this?

Comment: What language? Probably easier to find a [suitable email regex](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=email+regex) and then attempt matching that OR your username regex (something like `/[\w.]{3,10}/` depending on your restrictions) -- instead of smushing it into one headache-inducing regex.

Comment: [Regex is *not* good for email address validation.](http://ex-parrot.com/~pdw/Mail-RFC822-Address.html)

Comment: Would it just be easier then to use a regex that will allow ALL special characters for username? That way if they do decide to use their email address it will still validate and save properly?

Comment: @Skrubb In this situation , invalid emails would be allowed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this regular expression:

```
/^(?:[A-Z\d][A-Z\d_-]{5,10}|[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})$/i
```

The expression has two parts:

- The first part validates a username. Feel free to optimize this part for matching you own policy. The regex here accepts username starting with a letter or a number. A username can't belonger than 11 characters. `-` and '_' are allowed.
- The second part validates an email. This regex [validates 99% of emails](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html) in use as of this writing. However, you may use another email regex.

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

#### References

- [How to Find or Validate an Email Address?](http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html)

Comment: Won't having the length limited in the first part of the expression cause problems with the second part of the expression? How will validation know that someone is using an email as apposed to the first choice?

Comment: @"(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,20}|[a-zA-Z!$#\+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})"
I have this for my current regex to use a "normal" username with no special characters or spaces, limited to 6-20 characters, it's not validating the 2nd part of the expression though.

Comment: @Skrubb Use named groups, mark start and end of line, use Multiline and IgnoreCase regex options: `^(?<username>[a-zA-Z0-9]{6,20})|(?<email>[a-zA-Z!$#\+\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4})$`