# How to validate a field is email or username

Tags: node.js, joi

I'm working on joi validation in a node express backend. On the login screen users may input his email or username on the `login` field, and I have to validate if that is either email or username.
Which joi schema can I use in this case - two optional validation for one field, but required?
Any suggestion will be welcome.

Comment: how do you validate a username?

Comment: @AritraChakraborty it's not problem, anything is ok for example `Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30)`. But my problem is how to apply two validation to one filed

Comment: isn't it practically one regex validation?

Answer (score 4):

To validate more than 1 value for a particular field, **Joi.alternatives().try()** can be used.
Below is the sample code.

```
 login: Joi.alternatives()
           .try(
              Joi.string()
                 .lowercase()
                 .email({
                     minDomainSegments: 2,
                     tlds: {
                        allow: ["com", "net", "in", "co"],
                     },
                 }),
              Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30)
            )
           .required()
           .error(new Error("Invalid email or userName"))
```

Explanation: In above code, login field can either take email or userName and it is a required field, if the value does not match with any of the alternative then it will give you an error.

You can also use [ ] notation. It is shorthand for alternatives.

```
login: [
    Joi.string().email(),
    Joi.string().alphanum().min(3).max(30)
 ]
```

Refer [Joi documentation](https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#alternatives).

Comment: Add some explanation to your anwser please.

Comment: the [] version worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is practically one Regex validating email or username. You can user two regex in OR, or can combine both regex to make one.

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    login: Joi.string().regex(/emailRegex|usernameRegex/).required(),
});
```

An example is: `/^(?:[A-Z\d][A-Z\d_-]{5,10}|[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4})$/i` from [A regular expression for using an email address as username?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22815707/a-regular-expression-for-using-an-email-address-as-username)

For custom messages you can use two regex with name, check the [doc](https://github.com/hapijs/joi/blob/v16.0.0-rc2/API.md#stringregexpattern-name--options):

```
const schema = Joi.object({
    login: Joi.string().regex(/emailRegex/, "email").regex(/usernameRegex/, "username").required(),
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, it's really make sense. Btw is there any solution using Joi APIs? For example how can I apply different validation messages( `invalid email` or `invalid username`) in two cases?

Comment: Edited the answer, check if it satisfies your requirement

Comment: As I checked it's only validate the `emailRegex` and if not, throws `fails to match the email pattern` message

Comment: hmm how about this one 
    `login: Joi.alternatives().try([Joi.string().regex(/a/,'a'), Joi.string().regex(/b/,'b')]).required()`?